# How can a clock work if the uncertainty principle is true?

Tags: time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

If the uncertainty principle and Copenhagen Interpretation are true, then how can a clock tick? Supposedly particles can do all sorts of things when not measured, then how can they be formed into gears that make the clock tick when not measured?

Comment: Can you please be precise regarding your question?

Comment: Can you tell us why the uncertainty principle should make it impossible for a clock to tick?

Comment: @mmesser314 done

Comment: @PallaviRoy  done

Comment: How can other galaxies exist when not measured?

Comment: @jinawee Exactly. They are not being measured by us but by a grander force to hold them in a precise specific position.

Comment: h_bar is a very small number, and  macroscopi energies and time intervals are always way outside the bound.

Answer (score 1):

A clock is a collection of particles that behaves classically, i.e its a combination of all the wavefunctions of its particles, and due to that "coupling" it does not behave probabilistically anymore. You are refering to the phenomenon of wavefunction collapse due to a conscious observer, but in reality [decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoherence) occurs.

Wavefunction collapse happens in small quantum systems of $\approx$ few particles because even the smallest pertubation to the system will cause it to behave differently.

Comment: Yes that is the phenomenon that I'm referring to. What exactly makes decoherence the reality?

Comment: From the link I posted: "Decoherence occurs when a system interacts with its environment in a thermodynamically irreversible way. This prevents different elements in the quantum superposition of the total scene's wavefunction from interfering with each other."

Answer (score 1):

> Supposedly particles can do all sorts of things when not measured,

Yes, but that doesn't mean they're unpredictable. The behavior of particles when they're not being measured follows precisely calculable probability distributions, and clocks rely only on those probability distributions.

Comment: maybe one should add that unpredictability is bounded by the  very small value of hbar.

Comment: No, it's not really. The uncertainty principle is a lower bound in any case, not an upper bound as would be relevant for this question.

Comment: well, if hbar were 0 we would not have quantum mechanics, in that sense the smallness of hbar governs dimensions at the micro scale and is irrelevant mostly for macro scales, imo.

Comment: That's not exactly a bound, though. It's not like the width of a wavefunction has a limit.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about what is called the **Observer Effect**. Read about it from here [Observer Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29). Also, read some parts of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics). The **Uncertainty Principle** just says that there is a fundamental limit to which the position and momentum of an object can be measured.

Also, as PhotonicBoom said, the Observer Effect for Quantum Mechanics is not experienced at a macro scale.